# How to start SwiftUI List onDelete action with VoiceOver?

Tags: swiftui, accessibility, voiceover

I have SwiftUI `List` in edit mode (`editMode == .active`) and with `onDelete` modifier on some of list rows. I would like to make `onDelete` action available with Accessibility (VoiceOver). How do I do that?

Without any additional code, delete accessory (red circle with minus sign) on list element is not visible for Accessibility (swiping through accessibility elements just skips over this accessory).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `onDelete` is specifically for swipe actions.
Therefore, for `accessibilityAction`, I needed to add an additional function for removal.

**Example:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Text(items[index])
                    .accessibility(label: Text("Item \(items[index])"))
                    .accessibility(hint: Text("Double-tap to delete"))
                    .accessibilityAction {
                        deleteItemFromVoiceOver(at: index)
                    }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItemFromSwipe)
        }
    }

    func deleteItemFromSwipe(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        // for swipe action
        items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }

    func deleteItemFromVoiceOver(at index: Int) {
        // for VoiceOver
        items.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `onDelete` modifier, and SwiftUI will do the rest by providing Voice Over user with the next hint: “`<Row element’s label, value, etc.>. Swipe up or down to select a custom action. Then double tap to activate.`”

Even though you add `EditButton()` to your toolbar VoiceOver won’t allow you to interact with delete buttons(the red one with minus sign).

---

I assume it was made intentionally, to avoid making additional effort for VO user.